# Should we interpret ALL vectors of ALL vector spaces as having magnitude and direction?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, differential-geometry, vector-spaces, vectors

This question may seem similar to another one asked but it really isn't. We know that in physics for example, when we speak of space vectors, they are represented as arrows and these form a vector space. But there are other kinds of vector spaces for example, real valued functions on the unit interval [0,1]. The elements of these vector spaces typically cannot be visualized as arrows since that won't make sense for such elements so, we call them vectors if they satisfy the vector space axioms and that's that.

Can we also consider these vectors as having both magnitude and direction? I mean sure, if there is a norm on a vector space of functions, you can have magnitude but, I'm having trouble imagining directions being valid there. I looked far and wide for an answer and found none so any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: A common interpretation of "direction" in the abstract setting for a vector is the way in which the vector is represented as a linear combination of a basis for the space.  In the truly abstract case however, maybe it doesn't make sense to talk about a basis for the space in the first place, in particular for infinite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: If a vector space has a norm, it has a magnitude.  If a vector space has an inner product, it has angles.  If you wish to interpret $||\cdot||$ and $<x,y>=||x||*||y||*cos(\theta)$ that way, no one will stop you, I guess.

Comment: You can define directions as equivalence classes of the relation $u\sim v$ iff $u=\alpha v$ for a nonzero scalar $\alpha$, or if you like just lines.

Comment: I think that the direction of a vector $v$ is merely $d=v/\|v\|$.  And the magnitude is just the norm /|v/|.  Thus vectors in a "normed vector space" have both a magnitude and direction.  In particular, vectors in either a Banach or Hilbert space have both magnitude and direction.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek    I worry about the case where $\alpha<0$.

Comment: @irchans I don't because the field need not necessarily have that notion. BTW in my physics class a vector had magnitude, direction, but also "sign", i.e. you had to separately say which way the arrow points along the given direction (which was just a line without an arrow).